# How can i retrieve uploaded image (base64) full url from Carrierwave upload file to Rackspace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rackspace

I just need to get the url of my image (base64) that just uploaded to Rackspace server via Carrierwave.

This is my controller now.

```
def update_with_image
    user = current_user
    uploader = PictureUploader.new
    uploader.store!(user_update_params[:profile_image]) // base64 image like this 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2w...'

    // How can i update user_update_params[:profile_image] with the successfully uploaded profile_image url?

    if user.update_attributes(user_update_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
      render json: user, status: 200 ,serializer: UserSerializer
    else
      render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end
```

So after `uploader.store!(user_update_params[:profile_image])` how can i get the url of that file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean this ?

```
uploader = AvatarUploader.new
uploader.store!(my_file)                              # size: 1024x768

uploader.url # => '/url/to/my_file.png'               # size: 800x600
uploader.thumb.url # => '/url/to/thumb_my_file.png'   # size: 200x200
```

calling `url` method on the uploader should get you the URL. [github](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

Update: Quoting from carrier wave GitHub

You can optionally include your CDN host name in the configuration. This is highly recommended, as without it every request requires a lookup of this information.

```
 config.asset_host = "http://c000000.cdn.rackspacecloud.com"
```

In your uploader, set the storage to :fog

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog
end
```

That's it! You can still use the `CarrierWave::Uploader#url` method to return the url to the file on Rackspace Cloud Files.

Comment: Oh thanks! but can i get the full url of that include "http://myclound.rackspace.."

Comment: You should be able to get that. Just in case you're feeling lazy to go through the documentation, I will have that copied to my answer :)

Comment: It still doesn't work , so am i need to convert base64 `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ` to the other file type?

Comment: I'm sorry! I don't understand. What's not working ? Are you not getting the URL to the image ?

Comment: Yes it return `null` from `uploader.url`